# Jquery scrollTo scrolling a little too far

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im tring to use scrollTo, but when the link is click on the navbar its scrolls to the right div but just a little to far. Im thinking it has something to do with the fixed navbar a the top. How do I offset it?

```
<script src="js/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.nav.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#nav').onePageNav({
    begin: function() {
    console.log('start')
    },
    end: function() {
    console.log('stop')
    }
});

$('.do').click(function(e) {
    $('#section-4').append('<p></p>');
    e.preventDefault();
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you include the HTML and CSS as well? Or better yet, [make a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: have you tried the `scrollOffset` option?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(...).scrollTo( '#div', 1000, { offset: -50 } ); // add or deduct from the final position
```